# maven module main function using wrong filepath

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have literally spent 3 hours on this stupid problem, and I have looked all over stackoverflow and no one seems to have this specific answer(that I could find).

I will try to explain my problem as concisely as possible.
First of all I am using IntelliJ as my IDE.

This is my folder structure:

```
Utilities
|-----RandomFolder
|-----RandomFolder
`-----Java
      |
       `--MavenProjectFolder
            |----src/main/
            |           |----java/Main.java
            |            `---resources/test.json
             `---pom.xml
```

Note that the Random folders in this structure don't matter.

In this structure, Main.java is a simple file containing a `public static void main()` function in which I try to read in the `test.json` file like so:
`File jsonFile = new File("/test.json")`.

Now I know that after maven compiles my project, it is supposed to place everything in the resources folder in my root file path so (unless I am missing something) I figured that statement where I try to read in the json file should have no problems, BUT I keep getting a `file not found exception`.

After trying some miscellaneous things I tried to eventually place the json file in the root of the `Utilities` folder since running `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` seemed to indicate that the project is using `Utilities` as the root directory, somehow that seems to work.

**Now my question is, how on earth do I get my maven project (which should have absolutely nothing to do with the parent folder(s) containing it) to read files from its own root directory (the structure it creates when it compiles the project)?**

I have already verified that the `test.json` file does in fact get copied into the classes folder when the project compiles but `File jsonFile = new File("test.json")` still continues to give me a `file not found exception`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question:
`File jsonFile = new File(Main.class.getResource("test.json").toURI())` 

seems to grab the file from the maven compiled class path.